# verisign error -> Query to DNSKEY timed out or failed

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, bind, dnssec, fragmentation

I am trying to find the origin of an error I cannot get rid of on the verisign dnssec debugger
[Verisign debugger](http://dnssec-debugger.verisignlabs.com/ex-mailer.com)

Dig queries the server just fine

```
dig ex-mailer.com ANY @108.61.190.64
```

All of my logs are clean and error free in debugger mode   [Log output](https://bpaste.net/show/89155f71afb7)

In fact, the onlt sign of anything amiss is in a packet capture with what looks like excessive fragmentation  [image: wireshark]

The MTU on my NIC is 1500

```
vtnet0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=6c03bb<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,JUMBO_MTU,VLAN_HWCSUM,TSO4,TSO6,VLAN_HWTSO,LINKSTATE,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
        ether 56:00:00:05:53:09
        inet6 2001:19f0:6c00:8141::64 prefixlen 64
        inet6 fe80::5400:ff:fe05:5309%vtnet0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
        inet 108.61.190.64 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 108.61.190.255
        nd6 options=23<PERFORMNUD,ACCEPT_RTADV,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
        media: Ethernet 10Gbase-T <full-duplex>
        status: active
```

but the pmtu looks jacked:

```
ping -s 1500 -M do 108.61.190.64
From 192.168.0.68: icmp_seq=1 Frag needed and DF set (mtu = 1490)
From 192.168.0.68: icmp_seq=1 Frag needed and DF set (mtu = 1490)
From 192.168.0.68: icmp_seq=1 Frag needed and DF set (mtu = 1490)
From 192.168.0.68: icmp_seq=1 Frag needed and DF set (mtu = 1490)
From 192.168.0.68: icmp_seq=1 Frag needed and DF set (mtu = 1490)
```

I'm not sure where else to look. I am pretty sure this MTU fragmentation is the source of the error.

How do I get rid of this verisign dns error?

master config:

```
acl "trusted" {
        108.61.190.64;
        107.191.60.48;
        2001:19f0:7000:8945::64;
        2001:19f0:6c00:8141::64;
        108.61.10.10;
        127.0.0.1/32;
        ::1/128;
};

acl "outside" {
        any;
};

options {
        directory "/usr/local/etc/namedb/working/";
        pid-file "/var/run/named/named.pid";
        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation auto;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;
        listen-on-v6 { ::1; 2001:19f0:6c00:8141::64;};
        listen-on { 127.0.0.1; 108.61.190.64;};
        max-cache-ttl 1600;
        version none;
        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        allow-recursion-on { any; };
        allow-recursion{ any; };
        allow-query-cache-on{ any; };
        allow-query-on{ any; };
        allow-update-forwarding{ any; };
        allow-query {
                any;
        };

        allow-query-cache {
                any;
        };

        allow-transfer {
                any;
        };
        //forward first;
        forwarders {
                108.61.10.10;
                108.61.190.64;
                107.191.60.48;
        };
};


logging {
        category default { default_log; };
        category queries { resolver_file; };
        channel default_log {
                file "/var/log/named/named.log" versions 5 size 50M;
                print-time yes;
                print-severity yes;
                print-category yes;
                severity debug;
        };
        channel resolver_file {
                file "/var/log/named/resolver.log" versions 3 size 5m;
                severity dynamic;
                print-time yes;
        };
        channel xfer-in_file {
                file "/var/log/named/xfer-in.log" versions 3 size 5m;
                severity dynamic;
                print-time yes;
        };
        category default { default_log; };
        category general { default_log; };
};


#include "/usr/local/etc/namedb/rndc.key";

controls {
        inet * port 953 allow { 127.0.0.1/32; ::1/128; 107.191.60.48; 108.61.190.64;} keys {"rndc-key"; };
};
key "rndc-key" {
        algorithm hmac-md5;
        secret "KcnxhOeXddg8dRNrn9Qfew==";
};


view "external" {
        match-clients { any; };
        match-destinations { any; };
        recursion yes;
        allow-query { any; };
        zone "." IN {
                type hint;
                file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/named.root";
        };
        zone "ex-mailer.com" {
                type master;
                allow-transfer { trusted; };
                also-notify { 108.61.190.64; };
                update-policy local;
                auto-dnssec allow;
                key-directory "/usr/local/etc/namedb/";
                file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/ex-mailer.com.external.signed";
        };
        zone "nyctelecomm.com" {
                type master;
                #allow-transfer {107.191.60.48;};
                also-notify {107.191.60.48;};
                key-directory "/usr/local/etc/namedb/";
                file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/nyctelecomm.com.external.signed";
        };
        zone "emailingu.com" {
                type master;
                update-policy local;
                auto-dnssec allow;
                key-directory "/usr/local/etc/namedb/";
                file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/emailingu.com.external.signed";
        };
        zone "instaknowit.com" {
                type master;
                update-policy local;
                auto-dnssec allow;
                key-directory "/usr/local/etc/namedb/";
                file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/instaknowit.com.external";
        };

        zone "zippy-mail.com" {
                type master;
                update-policy local;
                auto-dnssec allow;
                key-directory "/usr/local/etc/namedb/";
                file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/zippy-mail.com.external.signed";
        };

        zone "190.61.108.in-addr.arpa"{
                type master;
                file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/reverse.external";
        };
        zone "127.in-addr.arpa" {
                type master;
                file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/127.0.0.1";
        };

};
```

slave config:

```
acl "trusted" {
        108.61.190.64;
        107.191.60.48;
        2001:19f0:7000:8945::64;
        2001:19f0:6c00:8141::64;
        108.61.10.10;
        127.0.0.1/32;
        ::1/128;
};

acl "outside" {
        any;
};

options {
        directory "/usr/local/etc/namedb/working/";
        pid-file "/var/run/named/named.pid";
        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;
        auth-nxdomain no;
        listen-on-v6 { ::1; 2001:19f0:7000:8945::64;};
        listen-on { 127.0.0.1; 107.191.60.48;};
        max-cache-ttl 1600;
        version none;
        notify yes;
        also-notify { 108.61.190.64; };
        allow-notify { 107.191.60.48; };
        allow-recursion { any; };
        allow-recursion-on { any; };
        allow-query-cache-on{ any; };
        allow-query-on{ any; };
        allow-update-forwarding{ any; };
        allow-transfer { any; };
        allow-query {
                any;
        };
        allow-query-cache {
                any;
        };

        allow-update {
                trusted;
        };

        //forward first;
        forwarders {
                108.61.10.10;
                108.61.190.64;
                107.191.60.48;
        };
};


logging {
        category default { default_log; };
        category queries { resolver_file; };
        channel default_log {
                file "/var/log/named/named.log" versions 5 size 50M;
                print-time yes;
                print-severity yes;
                print-category yes;
                severity debug;
        };
        channel general_file {
                file "/var/log/named/general.log" versions 3 size 5m;
                severity dynamic;
                print-time yes;
        };
        channel config_file {
                file "/var/log/named/config.log" versions 3 size 5m;
                severity dynamic;
                print-time yes;
        };
        channel resolver_file {
                file "/var/log/named/resolver.log" versions 3 size 5m;
                severity dynamic;
                print-time yes;
        };
        channel xfer-in_file {
                file "/var/log/named/xfer-in.log" versions 3 size 5m;
                severity dynamic;
                print-time yes;
        };
        category default { default_log; };
        category general { default_log; };
};


#include "/usr/local/etc/namedb/rndc.key";

controls {
        inet * port 953 allow { 127.0.0.1/32; ::1/128; 108.61.190.64; 107.191.60.48; } keys {"rndc-key"; };
};

key "rndc-key" {
        algorithm hmac-md5;
        secret "N/SB9HZwr5yRIBwtRjcA6A==";
};

view "external" {
        match-clients { outside; };
        match-destinations { outside; };
        recursion yes;
        allow-recursion { any; };
        allow-query { outside; };
        zone "." IN {
                type hint;
                file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/named.root";
        };

        #include "/usr/local/etc/namedb/tmp/zonelist.db";

        zone "nyctelecomm.com" {
                type slave;
                masters {108.61.190.64;};
                allow-notify { trusted; };
                allow-transfer { any; };
                notify yes;
                auto-dnssec allow;
                key-directory "/usr/local/etc/namedb/";
                file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/nyctelecomm.com.external.signed";
        };
        zone "ex-mailer.com" {
                type slave;
                masters {108.61.190.64; };
                #transfer-source { 108.61.190.64; };
                allow-notify{ trusted; };
                notify yes;
                allow-transfer { any; };
                auto-dnssec allow;
                key-directory "/usr/local/etc/namedb/";
                file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/ex-mailer.com.external.signed";
        };

        zone "emailingu.com" {
                masters {108.61.190.64; };
                type slave;
                auto-dnssec allow;
                key-directory "/usr/local/etc/namedb/";
                file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/emailingu.com.external.signed";
        };
        zone "zippy-mail.com" {
                type slave;
                masters {108.61.190.64; };
                auto-dnssec allow;
                key-directory "/usr/local/etc/namedb/";
                file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/zippy-mail.com.external.signed";
        };

        zone "190.61.108.in-addr.arpa"{
                type master;
                allow-update {none;};
                file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/reverse.external";
        };
        zone "127.in-addr.arpa" {
                type master;
                allow-update {none;};
                file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/127.0.0.1";
        };

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting all of this info, it helped greatly.

The Verisign tool errored out on:

```
Query to yoda.ex-mailer.com/108.61.175.48 for ex-mailer.com/A timed out or failed
```

The domain you're interested in is publishing two different NS records.

```
ex-mailer.com   nameserver = yoda.ex-mailer.com.
ex-mailer.com   nameserver = r2d2.ex-mailer.com.
```

From my own network, I can connect to r2d2 and query the IP of yoda. When I try to connect to yoda, I get nothing. This is what Verisign is pointing out. When I look a bit deeper, I see my connection attempts to yoda are getting `ICMP Destination Unreachable` packets from yoda itself on 108.61.175.20.

Interestingly, r2d2 is showing the IP address of Yoda to be `108.61.175.48`, but your config-file suggests it should be either `108.61.190.64` or `108.61.10.10`. Of those two the first responds successfully.

Looks like one of two things.

1. The A record for 'yoda' is off. It should be `108.61.190.64`, not `108.61.175.48`
2. The NS record should be pointing to the A record of whatever `108.61.190.64` is.

Comment: you definitely found an error, but it doesn't appear to be 'the error'  I am watching verisign like a hawk. some issues don't disappear for and hr or 2.

Comment: Based on the forced mtu, I really think this is an ISP error and reaching out to them. Also giving you the credit where credit is due.